# ganache-cli dependencies not found

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to use *ganache* and *web3.js* inside a *Next.js* application.

I run an instance of the *ganache-cli* in my terminal and then create an instance of *web3.js* using *ganache* as a provider with the following code:

```
...
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3( new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
module.exports = web3;
```

However, as I launch my application, I get the following error:

> Error in ganache-cli
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\ganache-cli\build'
>   ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\ganache-cli\build'
>       at factoryCallback (C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:269:40)
>       at factory (C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:235:20)
>       at resolver (C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:60:20)
>       at asyncLib.parallel (C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:127:20)
>       at C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3888:9
>       at C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:473:16
>       at iteratorCallback (C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1062:13)
>       at C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:969:16
>       at C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3885:13
>       at resolvers.normal.resolve (C:\Users\migue\Desktop\Microgrid-Blockchain-Project\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:119:22)
>   ```
>   As suggested by the error message, I tried to install the missing packages but to not avail. Removing and reinstalling *ganache* did not help either.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?
How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not just use the GUI? https://truffleframework.com/ganache